# Array of structs replacing values over itself

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Ok so I have the below code and I am just pulling various things from a file and inputing them in an array of structs, it "seemingly" works initially, BUT when I go to printing it after it is done with the file it seemed to have replaced all of the courses and names with the very last vale, oddly this doesnt happen with the integers (grades), the grades do get inputed properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    char *name;
    char *course;
    int grade;

};

void courseSort(struct student d[20], int size);

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char* filename = "grades.csv";
    char buffer[100];
    char* name, *class;
    char* del=",";
    int grade, i, counter=0;

    struct student d[20];

    if((fp=fopen(filename, "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("unable to open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) !=NULL)
    {
        name = strtok(buffer,del);
        class=strtok(NULL,del);
        grade = atoi(strtok(NULL,del));

        d[counter].name=name;
        d[counter].course=class;
        d[counter].grade=grade;
        printf("%s    %s       %d\n",d[counter].name,d[counter].course,d[counter].grade);
        counter++;
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<counter;i++)
        printf("%s    %s     %d\n",d[i].name,d[i].course,d[i].grade);
    courseSort(d,counter);

    fclose(fp);
 }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong :(  it all seems straightforward but not sure why it just replaces everything with the latest one.

Comment: You have to duplicate the strings. Because name is a char pointer to a string and all of you structs use the same pointer

Comment: like copy 'name' to another string and then store that new string into my struct?

Comment: see the anwers, they denote it more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strtok` returns a pointer to the buffer and does not allocate memory. Since you do not copy the strings, you end up with lots of pointers pointing to the same buffer that is overwritten at each iteration of the loop.

To fix this, you need to change your loop to copy the strings using `strdup`:

```
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL)
{
    d[counter].name = strdup(strtok(buffer, del));
    d[counter].course = strdup(strtok(NULL, del));
    d[counter].grade = atoi(strtok(NULL, del));
    counter++;
}
```

Don't forget to return the allocated memory with `free` once you no longer need the strings:

```
for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
   free(d[i].name);
   free(d[i].course);

   d[i].name = NULL;
   d[i].course = NULL;
}
```

Note that `strdup` is part of POSIX1.2001 standard, not part of C89. If it is not available, you'll have to re-implement it yourself (quite easy):

```
char *my_strdup(const char *str) {
  char *copy;
  size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
  if (len == 0) return NULL;
  copy = (char *)malloc(len);
  if (copy == NULL) return NULL;
  memcpy(copy, str, len);
  return copy;
}
```

Comment: Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast.
BUT it does work though o.o

Comment: Oh, this is probably because you don't include `#include <string.h>`. I've updated my response. This is because, by default, if a function is not defined, `C` compiler assume it accept any number of arguments and returns an `int`.

Comment: Then, the error must be in another part of your code, because if I compile it with `clang -Weverything` the only warnings I get are about the size of `struct student`.

Comment: these are the only parameters I am allowed to use with gcc:

gcc -std=c89 -pedantic -o

Comment: How, this is because `strdup` is not part of `c89` standard, but part of Posix. If you don't have access to `strdup` then you may have to reimplement it, I've updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here.

```
d[counter].name=name;
```

replace with:

```
d[counter].name = strdup(name); /*don't forget to free this memory.*/
```

the issue for the courses is the same.

Comment: I see more than one error in his program , its basically seems a copy /paste.

Comment: hmm works but complains about pointer to integer without cast

Comment: @PHIfounder What do you mean with 'copy paste'?

Comment: @hetepeperfan OP must have copied the error full program and pasted it  here , he should also show what output he is getting or what errors ?

Comment: @PHIfounder A I thought you ment I made a copy/paste. I misread your comment I suppose, sorry.

Comment: @hetepeperfan haha... No need to be sorry its perfectly alright, I wrote it quite fast so it may seem otherwise :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple misunderstanding of pointers and char arrays (strings).  Here are a couple pages that explains them pretty well:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

In your case, you are setting your struct pointer values equal to the returned pointer from strtok.  A lot of those string functions work by putting the result at a certain memory address and returning the pointer to it.  The pointer returned is always the same, so all your struct values are going to point to the last result of the strtok call.

This is why you need [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) (String duplicate).  Basically it takes the value at the address given and copies the contents into a new place in memory and returns the value.